# Display another alert depending on user response: OK or Cancel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where I have set up an onEdit trigger that pops up a ui.alert when a cell is edited. I then want to perform an action based on whether the user select OK or Cancel. This all works fine when I'm using the sheet as the user who created the trigger and script. If I share the sheet (with edit permissions) to someone else, when they edit the cell the script runs but I cannot get the response when they click OK or Cancel. The script just stops. Nothing shows in the Execution Transcript and even if I put in logging information nothing gets logged.

I've put together a very simple code sample that exhibits the problem where a second ui.alert appears if they click OK to the first ui.alert.

```
function myFunction() {

   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()  
   var response = ui.alert('Test', 'Test', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

   if (response.OK) {
      ui.alert('OK'); 
   }

}
```

[Screenshot of trigger set up is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbLnd.jpg)

The link to the test sheet containing script is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J16lpg9G1O8hQOxB-J1R4Oy0nsrxIkgWHBfaSl6bpVs/edit#gid=0

What should happen is that you will edit a cell first ui.alert appears, you click OK and then a second ui.alert appears. What I expect to happen when you try is that the second ui.alert just doesn't happen.

Any recommendations? Is it a permissions thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.alert('test',test, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

 if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
     ui.alert('OK'); 
 } else {
     ui.alert('NOT OK')
 }
```

--------EDIT AFTER COMMENT-----

```
function onEdit(e) {
//FIXED FOR OTHER USERS IF THE FUNCTION DOESN'T NEED OTHER PERMISSIONS (simple trigger onEdit)

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()  
  var response = ui.alert('Test', 'Test', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
     ui.alert('OK'); 
  } else {
     ui.alert('NOT OK')
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code amendments. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. The response is not read and the appropriate alert does not appear when the script runs as a user other than myself. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Oh that comes from the rights and the app permissions, the user has to allow the app to run for his account, even if the other user has the rights to edit the sheet.
If you're going to run simple code and you don't need to run other services you can use the simple trigger onEdit(e):

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the response incorrectly. Instead of

```
if (response.OK)
```

it should be

```
if (response == ui.Button.OK)
```

using the enum [Button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button).

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing EXACTLY the same issue with a BOUND SCRIPT.

I as the creator/owner of the sheet am not having any issues .

When i share the doc with another user within the same instance the initial  Ui.Alert shows BUT their response is never returned from the Alert, the var result does not get set , infact if i add a line directly after setting result it never gets there  ?

```
var result = ui.alert(
    'Approve leave for ' + ApplicantName +' ?',
    'An approval email will now be sent to ' + EmailAddress.toLowerCase() + ' do you want to continue ?',
     ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
Logger.log('Leave approve popup selection = ' + result.toString());//this is not executed
```

I have even tried wrapping this in a try catch block and get nothing !

> **Juan-Diego-Antezana**
>   "...Oh that comes from the rights and the app permissions, the user has to
>   allow the app to run for his account, even if the other user has the
>   rights to edit the sheet.

Can you elaborate on this further as it appears this has something to do with the issue ??

Thanks

Comment: Check the triggers documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers, how are you triggering this alert? if it's the same case, onEdit(e) does the trick for other users, If the event is triggered by some other means check if the other users have activated the script for them too

Comment: Yeah I am triggering via onEdit(e) BUT it turns out this is part of a broader, known issue, outstanding for 4 years ! :

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1728